# How to make text the same size on all devices in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

In SpriteKit, is there a way to make an `SKLabelNode` look the same size, regardless of the device, eg: Looks the same size on a iPhone 5 as a 6Plus?

I've tried using this method someone else recommended:

```
let textRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width * 0.4, height: frame.height * 0.045)
let scalingFactor = min(textRect.width / text.frame.width, textRect.height / text.frame.height)
text.fontSize *= scalingFactor
```

But it doesn't make all text the same size, as words like "man" aren't as physically tall as words like "High" (due to it's "y" and "h" sticking out).

So is there a method to make text look the same size on all devices? At the moment I create the SKLabelNode like so:

```
let text = SKLabelNode(text: "Start")
text.fontSize = 30
text.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
addChild(text)
```

Comment: what is your constant throughout all your devices?  will frame be the same number?  Basically I need to know if any scaling/resizing is going on with the scene

Comment: I'd want the font size to be for example 10% of the screen's height, no matter what device it's on. So it should scale with the screen size?

Comment: I cant answer that yet,  I need to know if your scene is resizing or not

Comment: Yes I believe so? Everything's size is based on % of screen. So for instance, a button's size is "frame.width * 0.5", but nothing changes once you're in the scene.

Comment: ok, lets make this simple lol.  show me the scaleMode you use, and how you create a game scene

Comment: You mean this? let scene = MenuScene(size: self.size);
                let skView = self.view as SKView?; 
                scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill; 
                scene.size = skView!.bounds.size; 
                scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5); 
                skView!.presentScene(scene);

Comment: ok the scene will resize with the view, thank you,  I believe autoconstraints will not affect what you are doing.  That is what I was worried about

Comment: Ah okay brill, sorry that took a while to explain

Comment: ok now that we have that in place,  your label should be a node, so instead of scaling your font size, you should just scale the node based on the screen %.  This can be done with xScale and yScale, so you dont even have to worry about finding the min between the two

Comment: if you can paste how you create your label,  I will create the answer how you should be scaling your label

Comment: Hang on I'll add it to my question...

Comment: Done, I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to scale the fontSize,  and this does not really play well with complex decimal numbers.  Instead,  after you create your label,  just scale that to the scale factor that you are using to scale everything else

```
let text = SKLabelNode(text: "Start")
text.fontSize = 30
text.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

text.xScale = xScaleFactor
text.yScale = yScaleFactor
```

where `xScaleFactor` and `yScaleFactor` are the factors you are using to determine your scale.  (This number should only have to be calculated once,  and then stored,  if you are not doing that, I would recommend making that change)

Basically in the code you provided it is done like this:

```
let textRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width * 0.4, height: frame.height * 0.045)
let scaleFactorX = textRect.width / text.frame.width
let scaleFactorY = textRect.height / text.frame.height
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more like an algorithm question. Think about you need to implement the same thing in TV, iPad or in the iPhone device. You should think about storing its absolute value rather than its actual value.

The formula should be `width for store value = actual width for this device / device width`. The same with the height. Then, if you use the same image data in other devices. You will just need to multiply the new device width/height.

Comment: I don't think it's that complicated, I simply want to be able to create SKLabelNodes, and have them look the same size on all iPhones?

Comment: It's not complicated. it's just how you store your width and height.